# How to use GSO for sending UDP packets

Tags: go, network-programming

Is it possible to make use of Linux Generic Segmentation Offload (GSO)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No

GSO is set in the Kernel, specifically the Network Driver. This [article](https://sandilands.info/sgordon/segmentation-offloading-with-wireshark-and-ethtool) goes into the specifics. Enabling GSO is typically done via the `ethtool` utility in Linux:

```
ethtool --offload  eth0 gso on
```

So assuming this is set, then it will effect all traffic going through the interface including that which is generated by a Go application.

It would be more difficult, but it is also possible to use the go program to enable GSO via the ethtool protocol. You can probably find an ethtool go package for this.

### Update

As you pointed out, you can optimize for GSO (after enabling it per the above information) even further by setting the segment size socket options. From the cloudflare blog you shared, the show how to do it in C:

```
setsockopt(fd, SOL_UDP, UDP_SEGMENT, &gso_size, sizeof(gso_size)))
```

Under the hood, this is done via an operating system Syscall.

I am assuming you are using `go-quic` as QUIC is referenced in the Cloudflare blog. `go-quic` can take a premade net.PacketConn, so you will need to create one from scratch and add the Segmentation socket option:

```
s, err := syscall.Socket(...)
if err != nil {
        // error handling
}
if err := syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.UDP_SEGMENT, gso_size); err != nil {
        syscall.Close(s)
        // error handling
}
if err := syscall.Bind(s, ...); err != nil {
        syscall.Close(s)
        // error handling
}
if err := syscall.Listen(s, ...); err != nil { // or syscall.Connect
        syscall.Close(s)
        // error handling
}
f := os.File(s, ...)
ln, err := net.FileLitsener(f) // or net.FileConn, net.FilePacketConn

//ln can now be used by go-quic
```

Note: gso_size is an int and must be known prior

Comment: According to https://blog.cloudflare.com/accelerating-udp-packet-transmission-for-quic/ additional socket options/ancillary data is required.